# Swift: How do you set up a function with no parameters to return a random array of numbers?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to return at least 10 random numbers but i am only able to return 1 random number. My code is:

```
func randNumbers () -> [Int]{
var numbers: [Int] = []
numbers.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(50) + 1))
return numbers
}
randNumbers()
```

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append at least 10 numbers into the array, so you can use a loop for this.

```
func randNumbers () -> [Int]{
    var numbers: [Int] = []
    for _ in 1...10 {
        numbers.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(50) + 1))
    }
    return numbers
}
```

Comment: glad to hear it helps @Geniouse. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem as you needed.

Answer (score 3):

Functional way to do this using `map` on `Range`

```
func randNumbers () -> [Int] {
    return (0..<10).map { _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(50) + 1) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer :)